# Outlook 2007 Creating a wizard to fill out repetitive emails I need to send

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, templates, forms

I have to send out an email to the same people every time we ship something (which is a lot). The email says the same thing with a couple of changes each time (Number of packages, Destination, contents, etc). 
Is there a way to setup a wizard I can open and it asks me things like...How many packages are shipping? Where are the packages going? etc. Once the wizard is complete I will see my completed email in Outlook with the said info inserted into the standard body of text. I have played with Forms, Infopath, Templates etc.

Anything Helps

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a Mail Merge. Create the template email in Word and then look at merging in the variable data.

Here are some links to start with:

- [Word mail merge: A walk through the process](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx)
- [Use Word mail merge for email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-word-mail-merge-for-email-HA102809788.aspx?CTT=1)

Answer (score 2):

Couple options built into Outlook that may help:

- [Quick Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/create-reuseable-text-blocks-for-e-mail-messages-HA010208653.aspx):

> The Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Quick Parts feature provides building blocks, reusable pieces of content or other e-mail message parts that are stored in galleries. You can access and reuse the building blocks at any time. You can also save building blocks and distribute them with templates so that other users can use the building blocks you created.

- [VBA Macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications):

> You can use a VBA macro to create a new message and preset any of the fields, including To/CC/BCC, the subject, expiration date, flags, voting options and more.

Here's one of many good examples related to what you want to do: [Create a new Outlook message using VBA](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook-developer/create-a-new-message-using-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a signature for this e-mail you send out, and then just inserting the  signature you need into that e-mail. After you insert the signature you can add the specific information you need to add such as, contents, destination, etc. Here is a link about it.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/add-signature-in-outlook-2007-using-the-ribbon/